# A non-zero function satisfying $g(x+y) = g(x)g(y)$ must be positive everywhere

Tags: functional-equations

Let $g: \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ be a function which is not identically zero and which satisfies the equation
$$
g(x+y)=g(x)g(y) \quad\text{for all } x,y \in \mathbf{R}.
$$
Show that $g(x)\gt0$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Look at $g(x)=g(x/2+x/2)$.

Comment: $g(x) = g(x/2)^2 \geq 0$. Suppose $g(x) = 0$ then $g(y+x) = 0$ for all $y$.

Comment: thanks. but how can one that g(x)<0 as wel? to complete the proof?

Comment: I don't understand: the whole point is that $g(x)$ is **never** negative.

Comment: sorry, i ment since we've already shown that _g(x)_ is never zero, how can one show that _g(x)_ is also never nevative?

Comment: @Sikhanyiso Brain and theo didn't show it was never zero, they showed it was always greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: @Ragib: Actually, t.b.'s hint shows both.

Comment: @RagibZaman, in Theo's answer, by assuming that g(x)=0,showing that g(x+y)=0,it's to prove that g(x) should not be zero, so as to satisfy the proposed condition that g is not identically zero

Comment: Yes. And both answers show that $g(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Put the two together, and you have the desired result.

Answer (score 10):

We have $g(x) = g(\tfrac{x}{2} + \tfrac{x}{2}) = g(\tfrac{x}{2})^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

Suppose we have $g(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}$. Then $g(x_0+y) = g(x_0)g(y) = 0$ for all $y \in \mathbf{R}$, hence $g$ must be identically zero. Since you assume that's not the case, there can't be any such $x_0$, thus $g(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.